# How to make navigator.sendBeacon use GET method

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain, navigator

I want to use `navigator.sendBeacon` in a client's website. But it is using the POST method and the request is not reaching the server as the request url's domain is different. I tried different ways of using `sendBeacon()`, but all are using the POST method.

1.

```
var data = new FormData();<br>
navigator.sendBeacon(myurl, data);
```

2. navigator.sendBeacon(myurl, "");
3. navigator.sendBeacon(myurl);

Is there a way to make GET call using `sendBeacon()`? Or is there any way to use `sendBeacon()` in a cross-domain environment.

Comment: maybe is a CORS problem?

Answer (score 12):

From the [W3C specification](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#introduction), on which browser implementations are based:

> The sendBeacon() method does not provide ability to customize the request method. Applications that require non-default settings for such requests should use the FETCH API with keepalive flag set to true.

Per this documentation, here's an [example](https://github.com/w3c/beacon/pull/27#issuecomment-241549321) of how the Fetch API can be used to replicate the behavior of `sendBeacon`:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: ..., 
  body: ...,            
  headers: ...,       
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  keep-alive: true,
})
```

Comment: Note that if your request is not a 'simple' request; to be more specific, if your headers are non-CORS friendly, then a preflight request will also be made before your actual request for security reasons. In such cases, the fetch call fails since "preflight request for request with keepalive specified is currently not supported". So as long as your `fetch()` + `keepalive` request is 'simple', this solution is good to go.

Comment: Two questions: 1. So this can be used for PATCH/PUT too? 2. So `keep-alive: true` is the only thing needed and e.g., `mode: 'no-cors'` (as exists in your snippet) is not necessary?

Comment: Also two other things: The spec you have linked to 1. talks about `keepalive` and not `keep-alive`... 2. says also "The user agent MUST schedule immediate transmission of all beacon requests" which is not considered in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although `navigator.sendBeacon` uses POST you can still pass the data as a `?query=string` and this will reach the URL endpoint.

You can then simply parse the URL on the server and extract the data that way.

I use this for approach to debug production sites when I want to keep the DevTools closed but still see messages in my local terminal. Here is the output...

```
navigator.sendBeacon("http://127.0.0.1:8000/?"+string, string);

127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:26:43] code 501, message Unsupported method ('POST')
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:26:43] "POST /?window-hidden HTTP/1.1" 501 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:27:42] code 501, message Unsupported method ('POST')
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:27:42] "POST /?window%20focus HTTP/1.1" 501 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:27:42] code 501, message Unsupported method ('POST')
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:27:42] "POST /?window%20blur HTTP/1.1" 501 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:27:42] code 501, message Unsupported method ('POST')
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2021 21:27:42] "POST /?window%20-%20hidden HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no full standardization of how browsers interpret sendBeacon();
some by default send on $_GET, and some on $_POST. they should use a 3rd argument to let the developer use GET or POST it would be more clear

Comment: What is $_GET and $_POST? The methods are `GET` and `POST`

Comment: All browsers use this `POST` by default.